# Transfer data from EditText to TextView of another activity using setText and onClickListener?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I am a newbie.. I am trying to get text on another activity which I have created, from an activity created apriori. I could do this using `onClickListener`, but I am unable to get it done using `onClick` and `setText()`. The code runs well until the second activity, but when I type and send button, the code crashes. Help me!

Here's the XML file:

```
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout="@+id/tv1"
     android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Here's the Java file:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        DisplayMessageActivity.class);
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
                String message = et.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you got activity `DisplayMessageActivity` declared in your manifest?

Comment: please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

This code can help you
MainActivity.java
public class Main extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button bt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(Main.this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("theText", et.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.example.theme.R.layout.DisplayActivity);

        TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(com.example.theme.R.id.textView2);
        tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("theText"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
android:layout="@+id/tv1"
```

with

```
android:id="@+id/tv1"
```